# Printing to printer error handling

Tags: php, printing, error-handling, event-handling

I have to implement a **printing (to a printer) program capable of**:

- looking for files (PDF, DOC, DOCX, XLS, XLSX, Text) to print from a specific folder;
- printing the files found according to the file    creation time;
- **handling printing errors** (log to a database and email to responsible);

The best would be a PHP script but if it’s not possible I can develop in anything else (C#, C++, etc.) as long as it can run on MS Windows 7 Pro.

As for PHP, looking for the files and launching the print job is not a problem (done by calling MS Word via a COM object) but **I have no idea how to get a response (confirmation or error code) from the printer**.

I have done some research on how to do that in other languages (especially .NET) but can’t find anything about error handling.

As for now, the solutions I can imagine are:

- Launching the print job from a COM object and then reading time to
  time events from Windows event manager to check for errors;
- Converting documents to PostScript/PCL first and then launch the print job directly by the spooler;

Do you see any other solutions answering the needs? I would really appreciate any advice on how to develop such a program.

Thanks in advance for your help,